# How to call a function in parallel in Go

Tags: go, parallel-processing

I am trying to run a function in parallel.... when I do it

```
func runParallel() {
    var out [5]chan string
    for i := range out {
        out[i] = make(chan string)
    }
    for j:=0; j<2; j++ {
        fmt.Println("\nStarting: ", j)
        go func() {
            out[0] <- f3(4)
        }()

        fmt.Println(<-out[0])
    }
}

func main() {    
    runParallel()
}
```

I see that function gets called serially one after the other... but when i do..

```
func runParallel() {
    var out [5]chan string
    for i := range out {
        out[i] = make(chan string)
    }

    fmt.Println("\nStarting: ", j)
    go func() {
        out[0] <- f3(4)
    }()
    go func() {
        out[0] <- f3(4)
    }()

    fmt.Println(<-out[0])
}

func main() {    
    runParallel()
}
```

The function gets called parallel.

I need to get the function called parallel in a for loop, Please help.

Comment: Please use **gofmt**! It makes your code much easier to read, and more correct. Your code had extra semicolons, and your second example wasn't even valid Go due to an extra `}`.

Comment: Put simply: No. Both "run in parallel" for whatever that means. Most probably your observations are flawed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keep in mind that goroutines provide concurrency, and [concurrency is not parallelism](https://blog.golang.org/concurrency-is-not-parallelism).

The problem in your first example is that you're reading from the unbuffered channel inside the for loop so the write that's happening in the goroutine is serialized waiting for the read.  Move the read outside of the for loop, and/or put the read in it's own goroutine and you may see more parallelization.

Comment: @ChrisDave -- The article that was linked is from 2013 (very old in the programming world, but still something that should be read) and while I agree that concurrency is not parallelism, modern versions of Go 1.7 (or 1.6 can't remember) and higher use all cores by default allowing parallelism to be achieved. Before this change to the language one would have to manually set the number of cores to be used with runtime.GOMAXPROCS(runtime.NumCPU()). That all being said, John Weldon is correct in his assessment about your use of channels.